# Angular2 => operator

Tags: angular

I'm currently reading the tutorial named "Tour of heroes" from and I have a part which is unclear.

I'm having the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }

    getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Hero[]> {
      return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000)) // delay 2 seconds
        .then(() => this.getHeroes());
    }

    getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
      return this.getHeroes()
                 .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }

}
```

And the next mock:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

All is running well but a specific part is a little unclear for me and would be great if someone can clarify me.

The part of which I'm talking about is:

```
return this.getHeroes()
                 .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
```

from service.

I've understood that first is called getHeroes() method which returns the list from the mock but after that what happens? :)

Long story short, what is the deal with `heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id)`

Thank you for your quick comments!

Now I understood what is the deal with '=>' but what I still don't get is from where **hero** object appears in
`heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id)`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I've understood that somehow is like in Java8 but where is declared the find method and from where hero object appeared?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Aren't it from './mock-heroes'

Comment: "=>" This is the arrow function operator, It add a nice and a more readable syntax than using a anonymous function as a callback. Also It has the benefits of maintain the this reference of the outer object. What this mean is that you don't need to worry if this is pointing the object which calls the callback, thus you don't need hacks like "var self = this"

Comment: no @Romanc. I posted the entire mock file

Comment: @Aditzu What type is returned by the `getHeroes()`?

Comment: HEROES object from import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes'; Also the mock list is added in the question from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return this.getHeroes()
    .then(function(heroes){
          heroes.find(function(hero){
                      hero.id === id}
     ));
```

It takes the heroes = HEROES, applies the .find() method.

The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

You could have used:

```
return this.getHeroes()
        .then(function(heroes){
              heroes.find(function(doesNotMatter){
                          doesNotMatter.id === id}
         ));
```

And still get the same result as the first one.

*Let's say that getHero(id: number) the id is 12*

On the first run

```
doesNotMatter = { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' }; 
doesNotMatter.id = 11
```

Does not  satisfy the .find() next

On the 2nd run

```
doesNotMatter = { id: 12, name: 'Narco' }; 
doesNotMatter.id = 12
```

It satisfy the  .find() it stops and returns the value.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Very usefull! Thank you! I supposed that find method parse the list and hero is the current element but I wasn't sure. Multumesc mult inca o data :)